# How to detect landscape or portrait; another desgin for each one

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to detect in which position is phone ? 
How to change a design for for each modes ? 
What is the best practices ?

Comment: I think this MSDN article can help you solve your problem. [MSDN: Handling Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OrientationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientationchanged%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) event to detect orientation changes on your `PhoneApplicationPage`.

For XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage OrientationChanged="YourOrientationChangedEventHandler" />
```

If you want to just get the current orientiation, use the [`Orientation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientation%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property.

For C#:

```
public class MyPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var currentOrientation = this.Orientation;
    }
}
```

For more information about handling orientiation in Windows Phone 7, you can refer to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).